# Print/log objects from an array using a for loop method

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

How would I print/log the name and age of each user using a for loop?

```
var users = [
  {name: "Michael", age:37},
  {name: "John", age:30}, 
  {name: "David", age:27}
];
```

I've tried setting a for loop to get the name and age but I just log the object

```
var users = [
  {name: "Michael", age:37},
  {name: "John", age:30}, 
  {name: "David", age:27}
];

var i, len, text;

for (i = 0, len = users.length, text = ""; i < len; i++)
{
    text += users[i] + "<br>";
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Michael - 37
John - 30
David - 27
```

How can I get that output?

Comment: What language? I'm guessing JavaScript, but figured I'm ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment you are only looping through your array. Thus `users[i]` will give you a particular object in your array.

So, if you want to get the `name` and `age` of a given object you can use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation):

- `users[i].name` to get the name of the `ith` object
- `users[i].age` to get the age of the `ith` object

Also, since your string that you're building (`text`) includes HTML (`<br />`), I assume you want to add the result of it to the page (and not print it to the console). You can do this by using:

```
document.body.innerHTML += text
```

This will add your `text` string as HTML to the body of your HTML.

See working example below:

```js
var users = [{
    name: "Michael",
    age: 37
  }, {
    name: "John",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 27
  }
];

var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var name = users[i].name; // get the name
  var age = users[i].age; // get the age
  text += name + " - " +age + "<br>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = text; // add the text to the page
```

Also, if you wish, once you become comfortable with loops and such you can use functional programming, ES6 destructing and template literals to achieve the same task:

```js
const users = [{name: "Michael", age: 37}, {name: "John", age: 30}, {name: "David", age: 27}],

text = users.reduce((acc, {name, age}) => `${acc}${name} - ${age}<br />`, ``);
document.body.innerHTML = text; // add the text to the page
```

Answer (score 2):

Another complementary alternative to the answer given by **Nick Parsons** could be using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const users = [
  {name: "Michael", age: 37},
  {name: "John", age: 30},
  {name: "David", age: 27}
];

let text = users.map(({name, age}) => `${name} - ${age}`).join("<br>");

document.body.innerHTML += text;
```